# Entity Framework Pass Object from One Context to Another

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework so please bear with me.

I have a program that I want to select multiple records from a table and store it in a queue:

```
private Queue<RecordsToProcess> getRecordsToProcess()
{
    Queue<RecordsToProcess> results = new Queue<RecordsToProcess>();
    using (MyEntity context = new MyEntity())
    {
        var query = from v in context.RecordsToProcess
                            where v.Processed == false
                            select v;

        foreach (RecordsToProcess record in query)
        {
            results.Enqueue(record);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I spin up multiple worker threads.  Each worker thread takes one of the items in queue, processes it, and then saves it to the database.

```
private void processWorkerThread(object stateInfo)
{
    while (workQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        RecordToProcess record = new RecordToProcess;
        lock(workQueue)
        {
            if (workQueue.Count > 0)
                RecordToProcess = workQueue.Dequeue();
            else
                break;
        }

        //Do the record processing here

        //How do I save that record here???
    }
}
```

My understanding is that to save changes back to the database you just call context.SaveChanges() but I can't do that in this situation can I?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do your records require lengthy processing or vary greatly in required processing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are disposing your `MyEntity` context in the first method (by wrapping it in a `using` statement), the entities that are enqueued will be in a "detached" state. That means, among other things, that changes done to the entity will not be tracked and you will not be able to lazy load navigation properties.

It is perfectly fine to dequeue these entities, "attaching" them to a different context, update them, and then call `SaveChanges` to persist the changes.

You can read about [Attaching and Detaching Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Add/Attach and Entity States](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! context.Blogs.Attach(existingBlog); is what I was looking for.

Comment: I still think explicitly loading the entities as un-tracked is a better way to go. The intent is clearer and doesn't rely on the context being disposed of before hand. 

In fact, in the code provided there is no guarantee that the context has been disposed before item is handed off to the worker thread.

Loading them un-tracked also means there is no additional performance penalty for loading the entities as tracked only to immediately detach them.

Comment: Furthermore, I feel this isn't the best overall solution. There is no mention of how large the data set is expected to be nor is there mention as to how long an item is expected to live while in the queue. A more robust solution is to save the primary key in queue and fetch the entity again from the database as necessary. This would keep any accidental overwrites to a bare minimum.

Comment: Off course you can explicitly load them un-tracked. But if you don't, why are you "relying on the context being disposed beforehand"? Can you show me some documentation on the "additional performance penalty for loading the entities as tracked only to immediately detach them"?

Comment: It's a given that if the entities will be in the queue for a long time, and you try to persist them, you could lose data. The question is not about how robust the solution is, it's about detaching entities from one context and attaching it to another.

Comment: I've experienced the performance penalty first hand. The context needs to search through the currently tracked entities when loading a new one. As far a the disposed comment, look at the code provided. The items are added to the queue before the context is disposed. Your solution relies on the fact that disposing the context automagically detaches the entities. The worker thread however could  grab that an entity from the queue and try to save it before the other thread has disposed of the context and an exception will be thrown.

Comment: I know the question explicitly asked about moving entities between contexts but given the sample code provided I feel a robust solution is warranted.

Comment: I haven't given him any code, neither did I say that, given the code provided, everything will work perfectly, I answered the question; Is it possible to pass an entity from one context to another? I guess it is up to him to choose what works for him, and what is robust enough. Feel free to provide a better answer :)

Comment: Or let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23579/discussion-between-kristian-hellang-and-sacrilege)

Answer (score 2):

It might be safer if you save off the primary key in the queue instead and retrieve the entities again. This way you are more likely avoid any data concurrency issues.